# Skip first iteration over unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, unordered-map

In a `for` loop with `auto`, an iterator iterates over an `unordered_map`. Like this:

```
using RuleIndex = std::unordered_map<uint, Symbol*>;
RuleIndex rule_index;
for(const auto & rule_pair : rule_index ) {
   std::cout << rule_pair.first << ": ";
   printList(rule_pair.second, 0);
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Assume all variables are defined properly, since the code works fine. My question, how can I exclude the first iteration? For example, the map contains 3 rows and current loop iterates for 0, 1, 2. I want to iterate over 1 and 2 only.

Comment: `auto it = rule_index.begin(); /* or cbegin() */ it++; while (it != rule_index.end()) { /* ... */ it++; }`, or something similar.

Comment: Interesting one liner

Comment: It's more like 6 lines...

Comment: @Biffen that will try to advance the iterator beyond the end if the collection is empty

Comment: @mtijn Good catch, `it++` could be replaced with `if (it != rule_index.end()) it++;`

Comment: `auto it = rule_index.begin(); if (!rule_index.empty()) it++; else cout << empty map\n"; ....`

Comment: Are you sure, that skipping **the first** row is always the best solution? `unordered_map` may change, well, order of stored pairs.

Comment: @soon: Yes, but I think the first row (rule) is always there according to the code. Under what circumstances the order may change?

Comment: It is implementation-defined. It may "store" the order for your configuration, but not for others. Just take a look at the [example (coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0537aa779c8d6ffc): the order seems to be reversed.

Comment: soon's entirely right: the order of elements depends on their hash value, how that's mapped into the current bucket count, and the order of insertion; even when two `unordered_set`s currently have the same elements that were added in the same order, different earlier events - including but not limited to `reserve` and manual or automatic `resize` calls - could resulted in a completely different iteration order.

Comment: Yeah wait this is a bad question. The title completely doesn't reflect what's being asked...and anything involving `unordered_map` shouldn't depend on order - that's literally in the name of the data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool is_first_iteration = true;
for(const auto & rule_pair : rule_index) {
   if (std::exchange(is_first_iteration, false)) continue;
   std::cout << rule_pair.first << ": ";
   printList(rule_pair.second, 0);
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The `std::exchange` call assigns `false` to `is_first_iteration` and returns the previous value. This is actually one of the use cases discussed in [the paper proposing `std::exchange` for C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3668.html). That paper also shows a reference implementation you can use if you are stuck with C++11.

Comment: Very nice solution with smart usage of STL!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use std::exchange (due to C++11 restriction), this simple solution could work as well:

```
bool is_first_iteration = true;
for (const auto & rule_pair : rule_index) 
{
  if (is_first_iteration) 
  {
    is_first_iteration = false;
    continue;
  }
  std::cout << rule_pair.first << ": ";
  printList(rule_pair.second, 0);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A terse C++11 option I sometimes use, which keeps a sometimes-handy counter too.  I've shown `if (i++)` below which relies on `0`'s conversion to `false` while other numbers convert to `true`, but you could put `if (++i > 1)` if you were more comfortable with that:

```
size_t i = 0;
for (const auto & rule_pair : rule_index)
    if (i++)
    {
        ...
    }
```

...or `if (++i == 1) continue;`... if you prefer...

While easy to write, concise and sometimes helpful, these may be less ammenable to optimisation than a boolean version - benchmark if you care.

---

Yet another approach that's sometimes useful:

```
for (const auto & rule_pair : rule_index)
    if (&rule_pair != &*std::begin(rule_index))
    {
        ...
    }
```